# How to make AWS AWIS UrlInfo api request using Boto3 credentials

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm able to authenticate and connect to AWSQueryConnection using Boto3, but whenever I try to get information about a URL using the 'UrlInfo' method, I receive a `204` response with no data.

```py
import boto
from boto.connection import AWSQueryConnection

conn = AWSQueryConnection(aws_access_key_id='', aws_secret_access_key='', host='awis.amazonaws.com')

response = conn.make_request('UrlInfo', params={
  'Url' : 'http://reddit.com',
  'ResponseGroup': 'LinksInCount'
})

print(response.status)
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I'm using this module?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am attempting to get 'UrlInfo' from Alexa about the url passed in the params: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AlexaWebInfoService/latest/ApiReference_UrlInfoAction.html

Comment: What is `print(foo)`? When you say "with no data" what do you mean? this is not shown in any way in your question.

Comment: Sorry, the `print(foo)` was a typo. When I say with no data, I mean that I receive the `204` response code, which indicates the response was successful but there is no additional data to send in the payload. Additionally, when I attempt to print the `response.read()` method, I simply get a blank line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was working on a similar thing lately, here is the code I was able to get working using [aws-requests-auth](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth), it has built-in support for boto3:

(**Notice:** host, region and quote method safe parameter)

```
import requests
from aws_requests_auth.boto_utils import BotoAWSRequestsAuth

auth = BotoAWSRequestsAuth(
  aws_host='awis.us-west-1.amazonaws.com',
  aws_region='us-west-1',
  aws_service='awis'
)

url = 'https://awis.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/api'
query_params = quote(
  'Action=UrlInfo&ResponseGroup=LinksInCount&Url=google.com',
  safe = '/-_.~=&'
)

response = requests.get(url + '?' + query_params, auth=auth)
print(response.content)
```

If you prefer to do it without any 3rd party library, you could always do:

```
from boto3.session import Session

aws_credentials = Session().get_credentials()
print(aws_credentials.access_key)
print(aws_credentials.secret_key)
```

Then go with the full fun signature process as described at the [AWIS Documentation - Calculating Signatures](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AlexaWebInfoService/latest/CalculatingSignatures.html).